# Difference between OnTouchListener and OnClickListener

Tags: android, view, ontouchlistener

I made an app which implements a `View.OnTouchListener`. But when I uploaded it to Android Market (Google Play Store), I got the following message:

> This apk requests 1 features that will be used for Android Market
>   filtering: android.hardware.touchscreen

I really don't need a touchscreen per se. You could also "click" the view and this would be fine. If I use `OnClickListener`, instead of `OnTouchListener`, would this requirement go away?

What percentage of Android devices do not have a touch screen? Should this update from `OnTouchListener` to `OnClickListener` be something worthwhile in terms of new potential users?

Comment: Maximum number of Android mobiles have touch screen so its better to go with OnTouchListeners than with OnClickListeners

Comment: Rosalie's comment above implies that OnClickListener doesn't work with touch screen devices - this is completely false. As cdhabecker's answer states, the choice is more dependent on what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OnTouchListener is for more fine-grained control than OnClickListener. If what you really care about is clicks -- i.e., the combination of of down-touch/up-touch/no-drag -- then use OnClickListener, that's its purpose.

Comment: I don't need fine-grained control, so hopefully using OnClickListener will increase the potential market. BTW I tried to change the code to OnClickListener, created an AVD with no touchscreen support, and enabled the trackball (F6 key in Windows). However when running the application in the emulator I did not get any visual feedback as to where the cursor was, and using random clicking and trackball movement I could not get the event to occur. Am i missing something?

Comment: I haven't tried a no-touchscreen AVD myself. I don't trust emulator features to work, so I recommend that you test your trackball setup on the emulator's browser app first. Also, try the emulator's arrow keys. If those are working on the browser app but not your own, then  perhaps you inadvertently set your view objects to be non-clickable or non-focusable.

Comment: @Rob Sounds as though this answer is what you needed; would you like to accept it?