# Work only one of listeners

Tags: android, action, android-relativelayout, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I have `RelativeLayout` with two listeners: `onTouch` & `onClick`:

```
 private RelativeLayout userItem;

 userItem = (RelativeLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.sliding_menu_userItem_rL);

 userItem.setOnClickListener(userItemOnClick());
 userItem.setOnTouchListener(userItemOnTouch());

    /**
     * Add user item reaction on click
     */
    private View.OnClickListener userItemOnClick() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "userItemOnClick");
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                UserFragment mFrag = new UserFragment();
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "replace");
                t.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mFrag);
                t.addToBackStack(null);
                menu.toggle();
                t.commit();
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Add user item reaction on touch
     */
    private View.OnTouchListener userItemOnTouch() {
        return new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        userItem.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        userItem.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sliding_menu_user_item_bg);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        };
    }
```

The problem is that onClickListener has reaction only when this line commeted:

```
userItem.setOnTouchListener(userItemOnTouch());
```

in other case work only onTouchListener. I don't know why. Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use both at same time , so if you want proceed with a special condition you can define a boolean variable, then return this boolean in your `onTouchListener` Listener,so with making true/false your variable it switches your `onTouchListener` listener Activate/Deactivate.

Same problems:

[Android :: OnTouchListener && OnClickListener combination issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188648/android-ontouchlistener-onclicklistener-combination-issue)

[Difference between OnTouchListener and OnClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742083/difference-between-ontouchlistener-and-onclicklistener)

[How to combine OnClickListener and OnTouchListener for an ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578718/how-to-combine-onclicklistener-and-ontouchlistener-for-an-imagebutton)

Answer (score 0):

According to [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29), returning `true` in `onTouch` means that the listener has consumed the event, so that it won't reach your `OnClickListener`. Try and return `false` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out to get both Worked easily

```
    userItem.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //Your work here
                return false;
            }
        });


userItem.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Your work here
            }

        });
```