# Android | What is the difference between setOnClickListener and setOnTouchListener?

Tags: android, android-view

What is the difference between setOnClickListener and setOnTouchListener?

Interms of:

Edited:

1. Performance wise, which is faster to load/respond on the view, and
2. Preferable Choice, this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122679/difference-between-ontouch-and-onclick-android), answers my second part very well.

Thanks

Comment: possible similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742083/difference-between-ontouchlistener-and-onclicklistener

Comment: possibly same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122679/difference-between-ontouch-and-onclick-android

Comment: have you tried this https://www.google.com/#q=onclicklistener%20and%20ontouchlistener%20android

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122679/difference-between-ontouch-and-onclick-android) explains the second part of my question, thx for sharing.
But i am also looking for performance differences, which is faster to respond on the view

Comment: @Eonasdan and other members: I have edited my question to narrow it down. Kindly reopen the question. I want to get feedback for performance between the two.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OnTouch is Motionevent. You can drag up,down,left and right. But OnClick is simply focusing,pressing and releasing. When you want to get co-ordinates of screen where you touch the screen, use touchlistener. Just a click event for button and imageview,use OnClickListener.

Answer (score 1):

setOnTouchListener gives you a chance for something to respond before the view does, whereas

setOnClickListener is fired after the view responds.